# getting elements from ajax failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    var text,replacing$;

    $.get('reload.html,function(response){
        text=response;
    });
    replacing$=$(text).find('td')
    alert(replacing$.get())
```

when i try to use replacing$.get() , it's just empty.

here's the reload.html (noting really, just putting it for the record)

```
<tr>
<td>
LOADED First
</td>
</tr>
```

its driving me crazy. response text works just fine inside the callback function, but never outside

Answer (score 6):

`$.get` is an asynchronous call using `AJAX` (in which A is Asynchronous). Meaning the lines after `$.get` will be executed well before the server response.

You should move those code inside callback as you mentioned in your post.